# Cordova: Loading Script From NoCloud Folder

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After upgrading to Cordova 6.5.0 script tags pointing to "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5FE2AAAC-BE2F-4B26-8B0F-F8BF6FB5C403/Library/NoCloud/resources/my.js" won't load in iOS.

Get Error "An error occurred trying to load the resource." in safari debugger.

Would really appreciate someone's insight on this!

Update: seems to be an issue with Apache Cordova wkwebview engine plugin. Removed plugin and everything works. Strange how plugin documentation claims file:// URLs are supported. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that your GUID is right?

Comment: @SteveKennedy As per update removed wkwebview engine plugin and everything works. This means GUID should be ok.

Comment: WKWebView has been fussy in the past with file:// URIs. iOS 8 would always deny the request, but iOS 9 should allow it. I find it easier to use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/wkwebview-engine-localhost which ends up serving content from a local http server instead (caveats do apply, though).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue with the WKWebView plugin:

"If your content src (the initial local file loaded in the webview) is in `www/index.html`, anything not under www will not load in the webview, even though it's a file url.
For example, if you have a file url to a file in the Documents folder."

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10237